Remove key value pair from from every object in array
I have an array of objects for example:
var ItemArr = [
  Item(id: 1, name: "Shirt", price: 10),
  Item(id: 2, name: "Pants", price: 20),
  Item(id: 3, name: "Tie", price: 10)
]

How do I filter out "id" key from my array of object so I get:
var ItemArr = [
  Item(name: "Shirt", price: 10),
  Item(name: "Pants", price: 20),
  Item(name: "Tie", price: 10)
]

This is how my object looks like:
struct Item: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let price: Double
}

I'm trying to insert a new row in my database (Supabase) that do not accept id since that is a primary key created automatically and can't be overwritten:
 try await supabase
        .from("items")
        .insert(itemArr)
        .execute()


Can you show a [mre]? How is MyObject declared? What are you going to do with the resulting objects? Why is having name problematic?

@Sweeper updated!

Create a new type without the id property and use .map on the array to convert to the new type is one possibility. Removing the id property from the original structure is another. or if possible with supabase, add custom encoding and decoding code for the type that excludes the id property. It's hard to say what is the best way forward

Could you create a new struct without the id and convert your array to use it instead:
import Foundation

struct Item: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let price: Double
}

struct ItemWithoutID: Codable {
    let name: String
    let price: Double
}

var items = [
  Item(id: 1, name: "Shirt", price: 10),
  Item(id: 2, name: "Pants", price: 20),
  Item(id: 3, name: "Tie", price: 10)
]

let itemsWithoutID = items.map { item in
    return ItemWithoutID(name: item.name, price: item.price)
}

print(itemsWithoutID)

Output:
[SwiftPlayground.ItemWithoutID(name: "Shirt", price: 10.0), SwiftPlayground.ItemWithoutID(name: "Pants", price: 20.0), SwiftPlayground.ItemWithoutID(name: "Tie", price: 10.0)]

You should be able to use itemsWithoutID to insert into your database.
